# Loop Through All Worksheets Except Those Named

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

The below code is intended to format column width, alignment and formatting on all worksheets in my workbook **apart from** those listed below, namely:

- "Contents Page", "Completed", "VBA_Data", "Front Team Project List", "Mid Team Project List", "Rear Team Project List", "Acronyms".

However the code only appears to run on the `ActiveSheet`, which is "Contents_Page":

```
Public Sub SheetCleanup()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Select Case sh.Name
Case Is = "Contents Page", "Completed", "VBA_Data", "Front Team Project List", "Mid Team Project 
List", "Rear Team Project List", "Acronyms"

Case Else
        ActiveSheet.Columns("g:g").NumberFormat = "dd-mm"
        ActiveSheet.Columns("i:i").NumberFormat = "0"
        ActiveSheet.Columns("B:K").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        ActiveSheet.Columns("G:G").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ActiveSheet.Columns("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ActiveSheet.Columns("H:H").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ActiveSheet.Columns("I:I").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ActiveSheet.Columns("J:J").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        ActiveSheet.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 27
        ActiveSheet.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 50
        ActiveSheet.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 50
        ActiveSheet.Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 21
        ActiveSheet.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 27
        ActiveSheet.Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 21
        ActiveSheet.Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 20
        ActiveSheet.Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 18
        ActiveSheet.Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 25
        ActiveSheet.Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 24
        ActiveSheet.Rows("3").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

End Select
Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ActiveSheet` is not changed in the loop, thus it performs actions through it. In the code below, it performs actions on the `sh`, which is changed.

In general, consider changing `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` and see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

```
Public Sub SheetCleanup()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case sh.Name
        Case Is = "Contents Page", "Completed", "VBA_Data", "Front Team Project List", "Mid Team Project List", "Rear Team Project List", "Acronyms"

        Case Else
            With sh
                .Columns("g:g").NumberFormat = "dd-mm"
                .Columns("i:i").NumberFormat = "0"
                .Columns("B:K").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                .Columns("G:G").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Columns("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Columns("H:H").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Columns("I:I").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Columns("J:J").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 27
                .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 50
                .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 50
                .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 21
                .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 27
                .Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 21
                .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 20
                .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 18
                .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 25
                .Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 24
                .Rows("3").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
        End Select
    Next sh

End Sub
```